# Nginx x-accel-redirec wrong redirects

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, x-accel-redirect

I am serving images processed by my django server using the x-accel-redirec header and Nginx. However, the behavior is really odd as sometimes I get the image, and sometimes Nginx redirects the image URI to my Django (uwsgi) application and I get, of course, a 404. My config is as follows:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/django.sock;
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name website.dev;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location /images/ {
      internal;
      alias /home/bob/images/;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/bob/django_website/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

This behavior happens with the same URL when I refresh several times. When I get the 404 error message from Django it says: "The current URL, home/bob/images/image3.jpg, didn't match any of these."

In apache with mod_xsendfile it was working perfectly.
Please help